# ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column via Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I am trying to run the below query in Access on a Oracle database :-

```
UPDATE tblQuotesNew SET tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status = 'Expired' 
WHERE tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='In Progress' AND tblQuotesNew.Date_Quote_Sent<DateAdd('m',-1,Date())
```

The data type of `Quote_Status` is VARCHAR2 size 255. The data type of `Date_Quote_Sent` is Date.

I am connecting to the Oracle database using the code below :-

```
Dim mydb        As DAO.Database
Dim myq         As DAO.QueryDef

connectstring = "ODBC;DSN=Comsales;UID=Comsales;PWD=******;SERVER=PDBREPT"

sqltext = "UPDATE tblQuotesNew SET tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status = 'Expired' WHERE tblQuotesNew.Quote_Status='In Progress' AND tblQuotesNew.Date_Quote_Sent<DateAdd('m',-1,Date());"

myq.ReturnsRecords = False
myq.Connect = connectstring
myq.SQL = sqltext
myq.Execute
myq.Close
```

When I run this query I get a ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column error.

Comment: Apologies, I'd left that in there for testing. Edited. Thanks

Comment: `dateadd()` and `date()` aren't built-in Oracle functions, and the semicolon on the end will be an issue too; but those don't explain that error number. Not sure what it thinks you are binding. I'm unclear though, are you actually executing this against an Oracle database, or against a linked table? ([this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101394/847) might be relevant?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running an Access query (using Access SQL functions) as a Pass-Through query (by setting `connectstring = "ODBC;...`).

This won't work. Either use Oracle syntax in a Pass-Through query, or Access syntax in a "regular" Access query.

For the latter, `tblQuotesNew` must be a linked table, and the query connect string must be empty.